# Criar uma ferramenta de consulta com Javascript usando select

Tags: javascript

Fiz um código em Javascript que a pessoa faz uma consulta do horário de coleta de lixo por bairros, porem ele me pediu uma alteração, queria que a pessoa selecionasse ao invés de escrever, até meu ver tudo bem, mas eu não consigo identificar o erro mas não está buscando, segue o código:

```js
consultar = function() {


  if (document.getElementById('ccidade').value == "patos") {
    if (document.getElementById('cbairro').value == "abner") {
      document.write("Segunda/Quarta/Sexta - 12:10 às 13:25 hs");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="frm">

  <select name="cidade" id="ccidade">
<option>Escolha uma cidade</option>
<option value="patos">Patos de Minas</option>
</select>
  <select name="bairro" id="cbairro">
<option value="abner">Abner Afonso</option>
</select>
  <input type="button" onclick="consultar()" />
</form>
```

Não consegui enxergar o erro no código. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ao executar seu próprio código funcionou aqui ... qual o erro está aparecendo para você?

Comment: Era erro do netbeans, obrigado mesmo assim.